# R code to get SAS like if condition output

Tags: r, sas

Due to business reasons, I need to migrate the codes from SAS to R. I am struggling with the below code -

```
if Date1 ^= mdy(12,31,9999) and AMT^= 0 then do;
            Var1 = 'Var1';
            AMT1 = AMT;
            if LOB = 'XYZ' and Date2 ^= mdy(12,31,9999) then do;
                Check = Date2;
                if Check < Date3 or Date3 = . then do;
                    V_Date = Check;
                    end;
                end;
            output output1;
            V_Date1 = Check;

            if Date_List1 ^= mdy(12,31,9999) then do;
                Var1 = 'GM';
                output output1;
                end;
            end;
        else do;
            output output1;
            delete;
            end;
        end;
```

Unfortunately I dont have sample data to share for SAS code. I can replicate the If conditions, the challenge I have is with the Output statement. How can I do multiple output statement in R?

Help Appreciated.

Comment: I would guess it is equivalent to R's `return()`?

Comment: The only issue might be if is is possible that you want one observation to become more than one observation. But it is hard to tell if your logic does that with how your IF/THEN/ELSE clauses are nested because the END statements do not align under the IF or ELSE. They seem to be randomly indented instead.   You might just want to split the conditions that result in each type of output as separate commands.

Comment: Thanks for your replies To be honest, someones else wrote the code, I am just trying to replicate. The data is compressed hence cant read it in R to check if the output is repeated. My first instance is that the output is repeated. Hence the output statement is required, and hence trying to find efficient code in R. Please ignore the indentation, I have chopped part of code (to remove sensitive data).